# Listen to button before button has created

Tags: javascript, function, button, addeventlistener

I have a function called `A()`, this function contains `addEventListener` for button click. As per my application, function `A()` is called before button has created. So button is being templated after function `A()` called. What's happen is `addEventListener` for button click is not working inside `A()` when I click on button. If I call function `A()` after button been created, `addEventListener` for button click inside function `A()` is working.

How can I make work `addEventListener` for button click inside `A()` when I click on button, but function `A()` should be called before button template

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like jQuery's solution for listening on dynamic elements. The idea is to listen for the click event on a parent of the button that is in the document when you add the listener, worst case scenario being the document itself. In the click handler check if the target of the event is the button you are interested in and if it is, do the actual work you want it to do.

Another potential solution is to "record" the handlers you want to place and apply them after the elements you are interested in are added to the document.